# assert each item in list contains XYZ

Tags: java, testing, webdriver

I am trying to assert that every item in a list contains the word 'hospital'
the following code gives me a list of every hospital as a string:

```
List <WebElement> Hospital = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/label"));
        for (WebElement webElement : Hospital){
        String servicenames = webElement.getText();

        System.out.println(servicenames);
```

What do I now need to do to assert that each item in the list contains my string?

Comment: Use lowercase / camelCase names for local variables. Besides, it's not a list of `String`s, so how can you tell if it contains the word "hospital"?

Answer (score 0):

```
List <WebElement> Hospital = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/label"));
        for (WebElement webElement : Hospital){
        String servicenames = webElement.getText().toLowerCase();

        System.out.println(servicenames);

        try{
        assertTrue(servicenames.contains("hospital"));

        }catch(Error e){
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
        }
```

For reference, this is what I've ended out using, sorry, didn't get the enabling assert thing - I've read somewhere that assert should be enabled as part of JUnit automatically anyway, (because it's used so regularly in testing I guess)
Anyway, this seems to be working for now...